# Probability of color picking

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a list of color term frequencies. Further I have some Events like E1=(black,red,yellow). I already calculated the prob of each color.

How do I calculate the probability of the event E1? If P(black)=0,25, P(red)=0,15 and P(yellow)=0,048 do I just need to add them for E1? This seems too easy and I think it is wrong. Or is it multiplication? Does the number of colors matter? Since it's not like i need to pick cards out of a deck..I am not asking for the solution, just a little help.

Comment: Multiplication, if they have to occur one after the other and are independent of each other

Comment: What does $E1=(black,red,yellow)$ mean?  Do you pick three colors in succession and the event is you get these three in that order?  Do you pick one color and the event is that you get one of these three?

Comment: I have a sample space which contains the color terms in a table.I have various events like E1. I just need to calculate the probabilities for these events. There is no order.  the event is that i pick these colors

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  Do you pick one color or three? If you pick three, do you make sure there are no duplicates?  The statement that order does not matter is part of the answer.

Comment: I pick those three colors

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a little more specific about the instruction here. If the events are independent (which is what I assume to be right). Then

$$\mathbb{P}(black, red, yellow) = \mathbb{P}(black)\mathbb{P}(red)\mathbb{P}(yellow)$$

Otherwise, it could be anything else, depending on the dependency structure of the events (law of total probability, Bayes or/and conditional probability...)

Comment: First, thank you. I will try to be more specific. I have this sample space wich contains the color terms. I have to consider the probability for each color with its frequency which is estimated witch: P(color)= frequency / total color terms in the table. Further considering the events, I need to calculate E1 for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not addition. Use multiplication.
Assuming the order of $E(1)$ matters, and each colour is replaced once picked:
Probability of $$E(1)=P(black)\times P(red)\times P(yellow)=0.25\times0.15\times0.048=0.0018$$
Assuming the order of $E(1)$ doesn't matter, and each colour is replaced once picked:
Probability of $$E(1)=P(black)\times P(red)\times P(yellow)\times3\times 2\times1=0.25\times0.15\times0.048\times3\times2\times1=0.0018\times6=0.0108$$
Hope that helped!

Comment: It could be addition if OP is picking one color and asking the chance it is one of those three.

Comment: True, but I don't believe the question is referring to that event.